# Question is not being reopened even after editing

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen

I had asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536307/) on PSE and it was considered off-topic and hence closed quoting that it was "Homework-like question". After that I edited the question following [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) guidelines. However, even after editing and making it on-topic, the question wasn't reopened.

My question is why it was not reopened. What more should I add in the question to make it eligible for opening?

Comment: Ii seems to me that you have got an answer, why do you want to open it again?

Comment: @PNS, that answer was given before question was edited. I've showed my attempt and I've doubt in that.

Comment: It already is eligible for reopening. One person has voted to reopen, but reopening requires more votes (maybe 5?).

Comment: @G. Smith, that one person is myself.

Comment: @PNS Actually I think it's quite a good thing when someone wants to improve their question despite already having an answer. It makes it a better resource for future readers, which is kind of the whole point around here.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was [reviewed for reopening](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/306653), and the reviewers unanimously voted to leave it on hold. Strictly speaking, that's why it wasn't reopened.

Now, to give a bit more detail, when I look at your question I basically see this structure:

> > *[a homework problem]*
>
> I'm confused that internal forces changes kinetic energy with respect to center of mass frame or ground frame? I found a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401727/can-internal-forces-change-the-kinetic-energy-of-the-system). But it didn't address my concern.
>
> ---
>
> #### My attempt:
>
> *[some work toward solving the problem]*
>
> I'm stuck here and can't proceed further.

As mentioned in [our policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714), we expect them to ask a specific conceptual question, not just ask how to solve the original homework problem or ask for help solving the problem. Basically, whatever difficulty you encountered in the process of solving the problem, you should ask how to get around that. That's the main thing you're missing that would motivate people not to reopen your question.